# Modificar valor de un campo en un mapa firebase

Tags: array, angular, firebase, typescript, ionic

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar angular/ionic y firebase y tengo un problema:

En firebase (Firestore) tengo una colección `User` y un documento `carrito@carrito.com`. Dentro tengo un array de mapas donde se almacenan variables.

[image: Estado actual de firebase]

Necesito cambiar el booleano `cart` a `cart = false` de un *elemento en específico*.

¿Cuál es la mejor forma / tip para hacerlo?

**Campos en firebase:**

`items` > Array

`items[i]` > Map

Para **añadir nuevos arrays** realizo lo siguiente que puede resultar de ayuda:

```
const newProduct = {name: productName, price: 0, cart: true, supermarket: 'Ninguno', bought: false};

this.afs.collection('User').doc('carrito@carrito.com').update({
   items: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newProduct)
})
```

¡Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar complicaciones innecesarias, opté por trasladar el array `items` a una colección que los documentos fueran mapas. Esto facilita en gran medida el trabajo.

De forma que se quedara:`User/carrito@carrito.com/items/`

Si necesitas recuperar los documentos de items, puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```js
getUserItems(): Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('User/'+auth().currentUser.email+'/items').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
        map(actions =>
        actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as any;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return {id, ...data};
        }))
    )
}
```

Esto devuelve un observable en el que siempre recibirá los cambios automáticamente de la colección `items`.